# Forgot password UI is not working properly in laravel

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, user-interface, forgot-password

I am using laravel default authentication my Forgot password page UI is not working maybe there is something missing in JS or CSS files:

Here is my HTML view of ForgotPassword and by default laravel us using @extends(layouts.app) and @section('content') but things are not working properly your help needs here.

```
              @extends('layouts.app')
           @section('content')
        <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">

            <div class="panel-heading">Reset Password</div>

                                <div class="panel-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ $email or old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>

                            @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
            </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>


                            @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Reset Password
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

@endsection

I dont know what is wrong here i am also attaching the screen shot of my page UI.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check your "network" tab in Chrome Dev-Tools (or similar). You should find that the `app.css` file is not loaded, and you should debug that error.

Please make sure also that in your `resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php` file a `.css` file is loaded somewhere in the head of the page. And make sure that file exists in the `public` directory of your project.

Comment: .css file is there under head and css/app.css and js/ap.css is under public folder under css and js folder

Comment: @syed1234 can you share the code of <head> part where css is loaded?

Comment: You are running your app in a subdirectory `feature-master` and probably you are includeing `http://localhost/css/app.css` which won't work because it should be `feature-master/css/app.css`